# Match attribute on XSLT instead of matching the whole element

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xslt-2.0

I want to write an XSL template that matches attributes instead of nodes,

I would think that having something like this:

```
<xsl:template match="@href | @conref | @conrefend">
    <xsl:message select="."/>
</xsl:template>
```

would match any of those 3 attribute names and print to console the value of the attribute as the scope is the attribute itself and not a node.

But my testing has proven me wrong and I'm only able to match nodes that contain any of those attributes like this:

```
 <xsl:template match="*[@href or @conref or @conrefend]">
   <xsl:message select="if(not(@href)) 
                        then    
                          if(not(@conref)) 
                          then @conrefend 
                          else @conref 
                        else @href"/>  
   </xsl:template>
```

The problem with that approach is that if there happens to exist a node that has more than one of those attributes then only one gets processed and I need to process them all.

Any ideas of why the first approach doesn't work?

EDIT1:
Full xslt:

```
  <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
      xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
      exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
      version="2.0">

     <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
     <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>             
     <xsl:template match="@conref|@conrefend|@href">
        <xsl:message select="."/>
     </xsl:template>
   </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Test XML:

```
  <links>
      <image conref="COPY-GUID/*+-862416}39-37CD-4CF7-A7AA-F09F4A763944" />
   </links>
```

Right now the XSLT is not matching anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can indeed match attributes in your templates as your first template does.  Something else must be wrong...

Take a look at the identity transform:

```
<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

It works fine matching alternatives as you're doing, and one of the alternatives is for all attributes (`@*`).

Now consider the `xsl:apply-templates` statement.  Notice how `@*` is called out explicitly.  Are you sure that you're giving your template a chance to apply to attributes?  If you're calling, `xsl:apply-templates` like this, for example:

```
        <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
```

realize that only elements will be selected, not attributes.  Note also that `node()` does not include attributes either.

### Update

Right.   Your attribute-matching template never has a chance to apply.

Add the identity template above, or something like this:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="//@*"/>
</xsl:template>
```

to give your attribute-matching template a chance to apply.

Comment: I think I don't fully understand how the xslt matches work, I'll update my question with the full xslt and entry xml to see if there is something wrong with that

Answer (score 1):

By default, XSLT does not look for templates matching attribute nodes. Explicitly apply templates to all attributes in the input XML.

By the way, are you sure that you want to use `xsl:message`? The content of an `xsl:message` is not included in the transformation output. Do you mean `xsl:value-of`? Also, if you output text, you should declare the output method to be text.

**Stylesheet**

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">

    <xsl:output method="text"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="//@*"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@conref">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Text Output**

```
COPY-GUID/*+-862416}39-37CD-4CF7-A7AA-F09F4A763944
```

---

Actually, in this very simple case, the first template would suffice to get the same output:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">

    <xsl:output method="text"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="//@*"/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This is because, once templates are being applied to attribute nodes, there is a built-in template that outputs their string value by default.

Comment: Mathias can you help me with this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67897747/how-to-get-following-sibling-from-xml-using-xslt-from-child-node

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your current approach is that the template matching the attribute/s is never applied. It isn't applied, because the built-in template rule matches only the root node and element nodes, and it applies templates only to children *nodes*. To apply a template to attributes, you must apply it explicitly yourself.

http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#built-in-rule